# How do you create a folder in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, flutter

File -> New and the context menu dont have an option of creating a folder, just files and other stuff.

I'm making a flutter app and want a new folder insie lib.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Or right-mouse click on a parent folder and New -> Package

Comment: So subfolders are called packages?

Comment: I'm just learning flutter and have never used android studio. Why are subfolders called packages?

Comment: @ArnoldRimmer I am not totally sure.  But I believe it Java-related as a class is part of a package. e.g. Package Name is com.mypackage.com.  I add another package called "activity" and add a class under that called HomeActivity.  The path of the package is com.mypackage.com.activity.HomeActivity

Answer (score 1):

Right click on the `lib` folder, select `New` and then select `Package`.